# strange behavior of zip function in python

Tags: python, zip

```
a = [1,2]
b = ["cat", "dog"]
ab = zip(a, b)

for element in ab:
    print(element)

(1, 'cat')
(2, 'dog')
```

but, I committed an error and wrote this:

```
for element in ab:
    print(ab)
```

then I wrote:

```
for element in ab:
    print(element)
```

that did not print any output, so my question is, basically, why?

Comment: you have exhausted your iterator, `zip` is usable only once, if you want to use it more than once, make that a list

Comment: You were right, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is because a and b are of type list, whereas ab is a zip object so doesn't behave in the same way. Try converting ab to a list

```
AB = list(ab)
print(AB)
```